# Functional vs Differential Equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, functional-equations

### Background

I'm under the impression that a differential equation has locality hardwired into it (which is why we see them more in physics). However, if I wanted to write something non-local I'd use a functional equation. I am aware there are cases where the differential equation has a functional equation form as well.

### Question

- Is my initial assumption true: "differential equation has locality
  hardwired into it"?
- Is the cardinality of the set of functional
  equations more than that of the differential equations?
- Is there any
  functional equation which does not have any differential equation
  equivalent?
- Is there any differential equation which does not have any
  functional equation equivalent?

### Caveat

While different theories of physics have different definitions of locality (for example bell locality in quantum mechanics and micro-causality in QFT) they all agree **one cannot send information (non-random message) from point A to point B without a mediator** (which is what I mean by locality in the above in the above).

Comment: [Why not both?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation)

Comment: In physics at least amongst the fundamental laws I haven't seen a functional differential equation (yet).

Comment: The heat equation has an infinite speed of propagation. If you take initial data $u^{in}(x)$ such that $u^{in}(x)>0$ for $|x| <R$ and $u^{in}(x) = 0$ for $|x|\geq R$, then the solution $e^{t\Delta}u^{in} = u(t,x) > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t>0$. So in this sense it is "non-local".

Comment: Sorry, can you give a link? And are you sure it violates: " one cannot send information (non-random message) from point A to point B without a mediator"

Comment: I am not saying that this is "physical" as it is simply a model. However this is what the mathematics tells us. You can see the solution here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation . In fact  $$u(t,x) = (\Phi * u^{in})(t,x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{{n/2}}}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4t}}*u^{in}(x)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional equations include the usual differential equations as a specialized subclass.

One of my favorite functional equations is
$$
y=f(x)\\
y' = \sin(f(y)
$$
It is clear that $f(x) = n\pi$ for any integer $n$ is a solution; it is much less clear whether any other solutions exist. This equation has no differential equation equivalent.

Differential equations only have locallity built in if you are considering the class of well-posed initial value problems.  Boundary value problems do not necessarily exhibit locality (although I guess that is a cheat because the boundary condition itself is a non-local matter).  Thus some of the most important equations in physics, including the steady-state Schroedinger equation in spherical or cylindrical coordinates, are non-local when the wave function is considered as a function of the angle about some axis.

In between functional equations (which when non-trivial are often impossibly difficult to work with) and differential equations (which often can be attacked by perturbation theory, and a host of other cool tools) I offer differential difference equations.  For example, for some given initial value curve $P(t) : [0,1) \mapsto \Bbb{R}$ and som initial velocity value $v$,
$$
\left. \frac{d^2 x(t)}{dt^2} \right|_{t = t_0} = - x(t_0 -1) \\
t \in [0,1) \implies x(t) = P(t)
\\ \left. \frac{d}{dt}x(t) \right|_{t = 1}=v
$$

Differential difference equation problems can have many of the same features as ordinary eigenvalue problems, yet can exhibit some of the same headaches as full-blown non-trivial functional equation problems.

The cardinality issue is not easy and may be subtle.  I believe the cardinality of the set of all differential equations is the same as the cardinality of the functions, but when you expand to functional equations, that may change.